# WikiMedia on a subdomain - creating a new page

Tags: subdomain, mediawiki

If I have a WikiMedia installation in a subdomain, like wiki.example.com, how do I create a new page? I mean, they said that when I put a link in the wiki, it would appear red. If I clicked it, it would send me to a page where I could create the page itself. Then the link turns blue.

But I don't think it is working for me...

Comment: Did fwa answer your question or do you need more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set some config variables and fix your htaccess file. Here is a actual blog post which describes all the steps: http://paulschreiber.com/blog/2010/07/07/how-to-install-mediawiki-on-a-subdomain/